# Is there a simple API for getting the number of unread messages?

Tags: support, global-inbox, api

Stack Exchange obviously has a complex API to meet the possible needs of its users, and it seems to require registering applications in order to use it.

All I'm looking for though is a simple way of getting the number of unread messages on my account.
(E.g. so I could be alerted without having to have an open SE web page.)

> SEND: "how many unread messages for user=#1234 password=XXX ?" (in a more appropriate format)
> RECEIVE: "3" (in any format that's possible to parse, and possibly with other data)

Is there such an interface (via HTTPS or telnet or whatever)?

Answer (score 5):

The API way, which is what the mobile apps used to use ... you can go to the [API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread), hit 'Get Token' (to make sure the site knows who you are) and then 'Run':

[image]

To make it work as an application or script, you do need to register your application and follow the [authentication procedure](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication); a while ago, I wrote a [tutorial](https://stackapps.com/a/9346/34061) to do so for personal use, which seems to match your scenario. You can then mimic the call by the documentation page. I don't know if that's simple enough, but I'm sure it's the simplest way ...